# UINavigationController's view and 20 points offset

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, offset

This is an already posted question but I need to understand what is going on with the following scenario. I'm developing an iPad application and I created a `UINavigationController` like the following (test purposes).

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];        
navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Once created, I added the `UINavigationController`'s view as a subview of a `UIViewController`.

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

The result is displayed in the following image:

[image]

As you can see, there is a gap between the status bar and the navigation bar of the `UINavigationController`. Since the view of the `UINavigationController` is red, it seems that the frame of the navigation bar has that gap.

I've found an hack to fix the problem. By setting the frame for the `UINavigationController`, the navigation bar goes in the right position.

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(navigationController.view.frame.origin.x, navigationController.view.frame.origin.y - statusBarFrame.size.height, navigationController.view.frame.size.width, navigationController.view.frame.size.height);

navigationController.view.frame = frameRect;
```

Now, since I don't like very much that hack and I would understand what is going on, do you have any suggestions to find an elegant solution to resolve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you add UINavigationController's view as a subview of UIViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That 20px offset is for status bar, navigation controller is designed to be full-screen, but you are adding it to the subview of the main view.

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean "navigation controller is designed to be full-screen"? +1 for your reply.

Comment: So, in iPad (0, 0, 768, 1024). Is it true? Is this a bad idea to use the navigation controller as I did?

Comment: Yes, it should be something like that on iPad, depending on orientation. You just should not add navigation controller's view to subview.

Answer (score 1):

```
viewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix that really solved all the problem. So thought of posting it as it might really.

### How this works

This gonna set my navigation bar origin to 0, and in turn the view of navigation is also set to 0 which takes the reference of Navigation Bar, which solves all the mess :)

And 44 is the heigh of Navigation Bar in the code. :)

Put the code in `ViewDidAppear`,

```
   CGRect windowFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
   //Setting the Origin to 0 of both Navigation Bar and Navigation View for Both Landscape and Portrait
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
       [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, windowFrame.size.width, 44)];
        [self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, windowFrame.size.width, windowFrame.size.height)];
    }
    else{
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, windowFrame.size.height, 44)];
        [self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, windowFrame.size.height, windowFrame.size.width)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

is deprecated. If you want to add subviews to your ViewController without worrying about NevigationBar use:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```